# How to convert the date string to users local format using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to convert the date string like this 2020-01-24T10:28:26.685502+00:00 to user local format..

how can i do it. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Try this:    new Date('2020-01-24T10:28:26.685502+00:00')

Comment: `new Date('2020-01-24T10:28:26.685502+00:00').toLocaleString()`

Comment: As @uminder has just said: you can use `new Date('2020-01-24T10:28:26.685502+00:00').toLocaleString()`, and then you will get something like this `"1/24/2020, 12:28:26 PM"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where your JavaScript code is running. If your JavaScript code is running in your users browser, you can just use the `Date` constructor as @Armen mentioned and it will create the data according to your user's locale setting in their browser.

For example, if you open up your browser console and type:

```
new Date('2020-01-24T10:28:26.685502+00:00');
// result for me => Fri Jan 24 2020 05:28:26 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Note that the time changed for my timezone.

Similarly, if you want to display only the date in a format appropriate for your user, you can use the `.toLocaleDateString()` method:

```
new Date('2020-01-24T10:28:26.685502+00:00').toLocaleDateString();
// result => 1/24/2020
```

Here, JavaScript is using my browser's default locale (en-us).

If my browser is set to Spanish (locale of es-us), the result would be formatted differently:

```
new Date('2020-01-24T10:28:26.685502+00:00').toLocaleDateString();
// result => 24/1/2020
```

If your javascript code is executing on the server as in you're performing this operation in your node.js app or you're using server side rendering, the above methods will use your server's default locale settings. In this scenario, you have two choices:

1. Trust that your user's locale is the same as your server's locale
2. Capture your user's locale => this requires selection from user in something like profile or account settings. This may not make sense for your site, though, in which case you would have little choice, but to go with the first option here.

If it makes sense for you to acquire your user's locale, you can format the date by passing the locale into the `toLocaleDateString()` or `toLocaleTimeString()` methods.

For example, if I pass the English Great Britain locale in:

```
new Date('2020-01-24T10:28:26.685502+00:00').toLocaleDateString('en-gb')
// result => 24/01/2020
```

The default for my (en-us) locale was 1/24/2020 (month/day/year) so you can see that the date format for Great Britain is different in that it puts the day first (day/month/year).